# How event capture of change of price?

Tags: price, jquery

I managed by DOM, but has some interactions, I need capture the last change, in **div.price-box** to to send a post via ajax, if not shoot several ajax post.

Example:

```
$('.price-box').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    alert('test');// display the alert from 5 ~ 9 times on the screen
});
```

The event **.change** in div.price-box or span.price does not work.

I would like to get an event that captures the change in price, or by my example only get the last interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$('.price-box').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', HandleDOM_ChangeWithDelay);

var zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer = null;

function HandleDOM_ChangeWithDelay (zEvent) {
    if (typeof zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer == "number") {
        clearTimeout (zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer);
        zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer = '';
    }
    zGbl_DOM_ChangeTimer= setTimeout (HandleDOM_Change, 0);
}

function HandleDOM_Change () {
    alert('test');
}
```

Comment: Dexxtz, could you please see if you can answer my question on similar issue at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312998/in-jquery-how-to-capture-the-html-when-the-product-price-changes